# How Standby Resource Manager figures out about the node and their respective nodelabel details when takes over the control?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

When Standby Resource Manager takes over the control, how it identifies the nodes and their node label information? I mean where all these metadata are stored and who is actually responsible to sync these pieces of information?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would guess Zookeeper. Have you looked into that?

Comment: thanks, @cricket_007 
Not in zookeeper but I tried some locations in RM like include_host file inside /etc/hadoop/conf but that only holds total host list on the yarn including for all node labels.  Any idea about possible locations in zookeeper to look for?

Answer (score 1):

Labels are stored in HDFS.

In yarn-site.xml, it's defined by `yarn.node-labels.fs-store.root-dir`

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/NodeLabel.html

Comment: What are the other flags and configuration files which are maintained for a complete failover recovery when the resource manager goes down?

Comment: I assume you mean NodeManagers. ResourceManagers don't have standbys. That's documented here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html

Comment: Also, who is responsible for maintaining node and their node label details in HDFS?

Comment: I would guess the resource manager reports its labels to the node manager, which then stores in HDFS

Comment: To your previous question - No, the whole setup is in HA with 3 nodes for each(RM and NM). But when active RM goes down, it loses node and their node label info and adds all nodes to default partition. That's why I wanted to know these meta informations to debug the root cause.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't have more than two RM, one active and one standby. I would check the yarn-site.xml between all machines for differences

Comment: As per the Apache docs, In RM HA architecture - at any point of time, one of the RMs is Active, and one or more RMs are in Standby mode waiting to take over should anything happen to the Active.

Ref. [https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html]

Comment: How and when `Shutdown Nodes` are cleared from yarn? increasing this to al very large value increasing the yarn load.

Comment: Hi, @cricket_007 sorry if I was not clear but I wanted to know how can I remove the shutdown nodes from yarn? They are already dead nodes.